# Why is CloudFront working via one CNAME record but not another?

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-cloudfront, route53

So assume company name is **widget**

I have elastic beanstalk instance at **widget.elasticbeanstalk.com**
I have a domain name **widget.com** under Route53 control
I have a CNAME record **direct.widget.com** pointing to **widget.elasticbeanstalk.com**
I have another  CNAME record **search.widget.com** also pointing to **widget.elasticbeanstalk.com**

This works fine I can access my eb instance via **search.widget.com** and **direct.widget.com**

I then setup Cloudfront to use origin **direct.widget.com** with alternate domain name of **cache.widget.com**, and I configure another CNAME on Route53 from **cache.widget.com** to my cloudfront instance (lets call this **drvevtora80lk.cloudfront.net**)

This also works fine I can access my Cloudfront instance via **cache.widget.com** and this will recognise already cached data and work or go to **direct.widget.com** as necessary.

But my users are using **search.widget.com** and I want them to now go via Cloudfront rather than directly to the server. So I now modify the **search.widget.com** CNAME to point to **drvevtora80lk.cloudfront.net** and wait a while for changes to propogate.

But now using **search.widget.com** gives me a Cloudfront error

The **cache.widget.com** and **direct.widget.com** continue to work fine, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I do a dig for search .widget.com and see *search.widget.com.      14400   IN      A       188.121.62.153* an A record.

Comment: widget was just an example , actually if you want the real names replace widget with jthinkws

Comment: search.jthinkws.com does a 302 redirect to jthink.net. Is that what you intended? You can check any .htaccess (or other similar mechanism) to ensure that you are doing what you want.

Comment: Yes (thats defined on EB) but it only does that if don't pass a query

Comment: e.g http://search.jthinkws.com/?type=release&query=reid:44 AND src:2 works and http://cache.jthinkws.com/?type=release&query=reid:44 AND src:2 works but if I set search.jthinkws.com to go to Cloudfront it gave error

Comment: Using your links, I get the same XML with a 200 Success code. Have you cleared your browser cache?? We all forget to do this from time to time. Even after 30 years!!

Comment: @closenoc Sorry, I put search.jthinkws.com back to point at direct.jthinkws.com because it is being used by customers, so I couldnt leave it. Okay Ive now created search2.jthinkws.com and pointed it to cloudfront as you can see it gives a cloudfront error  http://search2.jthinkws.com/?type=release&query=reid:44 AND src:2

Comment: Okay. I see search2.jthinkws.com is a cname for drvevtora86lk.cloudfront.net. When I access http://search2.jthinkws.com/?type=release&query=reid:44, I get a 403 Forbidden. This tells me that it is ***not*** actually trying to run the app. Is there anything in your .htaccess that handles requests for cache.jthinkws.com that should also handle search2.jthinkws.com??

Comment: @closetnoc just realized that on Cloudfront I hadn't set search2.jthinkws.com as an alternate cname on Cloufront) (i guess this is similar to .htaccess). Added now, not yet had any effect but perhaps I just need to wait

Comment: Let us know how it works out for you. We are here though weekends tend to be a bit slower. ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc yes it does work now, thx

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that although I modified the search.widget.com CNAME to point to drvevtora80lk.cloudfront.net I forgot to add search.widget.com as an alternate name within my CloudFront distribution, added that and it now works.